# Icon issues localNotificationsPlugin, how to add app Icon the right way

Tags: android, flutter, dart, push-notification, scheduled-tasks

I have implemented local push notifications in flutter app. This plugin was working smoothly at first. The issues came when I had run `flutter clean` and also uninstalling the app on android Emulator to do a clean install with `flutter run`. After doing so the app crashes on startup.

When run the app in debugging mode, it is showing that the error is happening on `await localNotificationsPlugin.initialize`. Debugger showing statement below.

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(INVALID_ICON, The resource ic_launcher could not be found. Please make sure it has been added as a drawable resource to your Android head project., null))
```

Code below is showing how I have implemented the localNotificationsPlugin.

```dart
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin localNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  initializeNotifications() async {
    var initAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');
    var initIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initSettings = InitializationSettings(initAndroid, initIOS);

    await localNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initSettings,
      onSelectNotification: gotToNotificationsPage,
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeNotifications();
    showNotification();
  }

  Future singleNotification(
      DateTime datetime, String message, String subtext, int hashcode,
      {String sound}) async {
    var androidChannel = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel-id',
      'channel-name',
      'channel-description',
      importance: Importance.Max,
      priority: Priority.Max,
    );

    var iosChannel = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannel = NotificationDetails(androidChannel, iosChannel);
    localNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
        hashcode, message, subtext, datetime, platformChannel,
        payload: hashcode.toString());
  }

  showNotification() async {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now().toUtc().add(
          Duration(seconds: 5),
        );

    await singleNotification(
      now,
      'Notification',
      'This is a notification',
      98123871,
    );
  }

  Future gotToNotificationsPage(String payload) {
    return Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/notifications');
  }
```

**Note** the problem is on `await localNotificationsPlugin.initialize` I'm failing to assign app Icon properly. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that you have an `ic_launcher` icon available on the res folder or try to add a new icon in drawable and use `AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_my_new_notification_icon')`

Comment: Can u send link to any tutorials?

Comment: https://medium.com/@nitishk72/flutter-local-notification-1e43a353877b Try this

Comment: Also, you are calling showNotification just after setting up the notification and setting up the notification is an async operation. So that can alos cause issues

Comment: @KrishnakumarCN Thanks man. The app isn't crashing anymore. And the notification is showing alright.

Answer (score -1):

To set a custom icon, you can add an app_icon.png inside `android/app/src/res/drawable`, then initialize it with

```dart
const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');`
```

Otherwise, if you'd like to use the default app icon, you can set the app icon on AndroidInitializationSettings with `@mipmap/ic_launcher`

If you're unsure on where to start, you can try out the [sample](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/tree/master/flutter_local_notifications/example) provided by the plugin on GitHub.